# Lucene IndexWriters in @Singleton @ApplicationScoped bean closes the IndexWriter

Tags: java, indexing, lucene

I need to index document while they are being uploaded into different indexes based on their content in a Java web application where multiple users can be uploading multiple documents each simoultaneously

I am using Lucene 6.2.1 for indexing

for this I have created a Stateless EJB. which Indexes the document while it is being uploaded called IndexingSessionBean

But as I can not have multiple IndexWriters open on one index I have created a @Singleton and @ApplicationScoped bean called CatagoryIndexWriters, which should have a map of Index writers for each catagory of document and pass it to IndexingSessionBean.

my code is as given below

**IndexingSessionBean.java**

```
@Stateless
public class IndexingSessionBean {
    @EJB
    CatagoryIndexWriters catagoryIndexWriters;

    public void indexFile(String documentId, String catId, byte[] fileBytes, boolean isUpdate) {

        String content = // get contents of the fileBytes in String

        try {
            IndexWriter writer = catagoryIndexWriters.getTargetIndexWriter(catId)
            Document doc = new Document();
            Field documentIdField = new StringField("documentId", documentId, Field.Store.YES);
            doc.add(documentIdField);
            doc.add(new TextField("contents", content, Field.Store.YES));
            if (!isUpdate) {
                LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Indexing file with documentId {0}", documentId);
                writer.addDocument(doc);
            } else {
                LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Updating Index for file with documentId {0}", documentId);
                writer.updateDocument(new Term("documentId", documentId), doc);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Unable to index document!", ex);
        }

    }
}
```

**CatagoryIndexWriters**

```
@Singleton
@ApplicationScoped
@ConcurrencyManagement(BEAN)
public class CatagoryIndexWriters {

    @EJB
    SystemConfigBean systemConfigBean;


    Map<String, IndexWriter> indexWritersMap =new HashMap<String, IndexWriter>();
    private double RAMBufferSize = 256.00;

    public IndexWriter getCatagoryIndexWriter(String catId){
        IndexWriter writer;
        writer = indexWritersMap.get(catId);
        if (writer != null){
            return writer;
        }else{
            addCatagoryIndexWriterToMap(catId);
            return indexWritersMap.get(catId);
        }

    }

    private void createCatagoryIndexPath(String catId){
        String indexPath = systemConfigBean.getSearchindexPath();
        String catIndexPathString = indexPath+systemConfigBean.SEPARATORCHAR+catId;
        Path catIndexPath = new File(catIndexPathString).toPath();

        //Check the Catagory Index Folder if there is no index folder create it.

    }

    private void addCatagoryIndexWriterToMap(String catId){
        createCatagoryIndexPath(catId);
        String indexPath = systemConfigBean.getSearchindexPath();
        String catIndexPathString = indexPath+systemConfigBean.SEPARATORCHAR+catId;
        Path catIndexPath = new File(catIndexPathString).toPath();

        try {
            Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(catIndexPath);
            Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
            IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
            iwc.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
            iwc.setRAMBufferSizeMB(this.RAMBufferSize);
            try (IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, iwc)) {
                indexWritersMap.put(catId, writer);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But while adding document I get following exception..

```
Mai 12, 2017 12:54:59 PM org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.EjbTransactionUtil handleSystemException
SCHWERWIEGEND: EjbTransactionUtil.handleSystemException: this IndexWriter is closed
org.apache.lucene.store.AlreadyClosedException: this IndexWriter is closed
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.ensureOpen(IndexWriter.java:740)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.ensureOpen(IndexWriter.java:754)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1558)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.addDocument(IndexWriter.java:1307)
        at de.zaffar.docloaddoc.beans.IndexingSessionBean.indexFile(IndexingSessionBean.java:257)
```

I dont know from where the close method in IndexWriter bieng called

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be the line , `try (IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, iwc))` so this resource will be auto closed after try statement i.e. once you have put it into map.

[try-with-resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) has a very specific use case of using that resource with in the try - block otherwise it will be closed.

`IndexWriter`does implement `AutoCloseable` so it gets closed.

Remove it from try-with-resource and make it a normal statement then try again.

Comment: On SO, you can answer your own question if you found solution later. That way folks would know that you have solved your problem and wouldn't try to answer.

Comment: came to SOF to answer it ... but found your helpfull reply... thanks anyways